# Accumulated value from many rasters python/arcgis10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, raster

I need to calculate an accumulated value of temperature (as an additional raster) from many rasters.

Is there any option to do this in ArcGIS 10 or any hints for a python script?

Comment: What about using the **Raster Calculator** with an expression `"Raster_1" + "Raster_2" + "Raster_3"...` and setting the output layer?

Comment: You mean just regular 'sum up'?

Comment: Pretty much yes, this is what I did using QGIS although I only had 5 raster layers and only needed a basic summing up, you mentioned "many" so there's probably a simple arcpy script which could do this for multiple raster layers. Hopefully others can advise if this is the case.

Comment: Have you looked at [cell statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) was designed for this type of operation.  This is how you would implement cell statistics with Python:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Define input workspace and create list of rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\your\rasters'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

# Run cell statistics
calc = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics(rasters, statistics_type = "SUM")
calc.save(r'C:\path\to\output\raster.img')
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, perfect! it works. Do not know why it (CellStat) did not work in ModelBulder and this is the reason I asked.

Also, I found that way, a little bit around/longer.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
# Define input workspace and create list of rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = r'X:\path\to\rasters'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

i = 0
    #loop through rasters in list
for raster in rasters:
    #print raster
#sum rasters together
if i == 0:
    outSUM = arcpy.Raster(raster)
    i += 1
else:
    outSUM = outSUM + raster
    i += 1

#save final output to the current workspace
outSUM.save('sumRas')
```

from https://geonet.esri.com/thread/25945

Both work!

Thank you all!

Comment: What if I would like to save each raster step by step: sum1, sum2; not only the final product?

Comment: I would advise asking a new question for that.